# Dynamically change class based on current index in a react component. (object.map)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have this Object.map statement in a react component.

```
{
  instagramItems.map((item, index) => (

    <div className="row" Key={index}>
      <div onClick={() => handleClick(item, index)} className="image-block col-sm-4" style={{
        backgroundImage: "url(" + item.media_url + ")",
        backgroundPosition: 'center ',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
      }}></div>
```

I want to change the col-sm-X class on a div so the out put repeats this pattern.

```
col-sm-4

col-sm-8

col-sm-4

col-sm-4

col-sm-4

col-sm-8

col-sm-4
```

I'm guessing I need to use the Index to calculate what I need to set the class to.

**Update:**

Though I have marked Yuji 'Tomita' Tomita answer as the correct one. It is not exactly what I wanted...

I want the pattern to repeat not just have diffrent classes for the first and the last. I want the out put to be like this:

http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-template/responsive-image-tiles

Can anyone improve the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. If it has logic behind it, i.e. "item 2, and second from last" are 8, then you can code that in.

```
`col-sm-${index === 1 || index === myArray.length-2 ? 8: 4}`
```

Or, you could have a separate array of classes if they follow no pattern and pull the loop index.

```
const cols = [4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8]
const myArray.map((x, i) => <div className={cols[i]}></div>)
```

How you go about it is more of a developer experience kind of thing. What pattern is easiest to understand/maintain/etc

Comment: @pilchard classic

Comment: I am trying
className="image-block col-sm-${index === 1 || index === myArray.length-2 ? 8: 4}"

but How do I escape the string?

Comment: @AyoAdesina use `{}` to use javascript. Inside {} is pure javascript. className={"foo" + 4}

Comment: Oh, you're using template escaping in which case you need to use a template literal, className={`....`}

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita like this:
className={"image-block col-sm-" + index === 1 || index === item.length - 2 ? 8 : 4}

Not working... can you be more specfic?

Comment: @AyoAdesina yup that would work. Define not working. What do you see. Oh, order of operations. Add a parenthesis to the ternary. Generally speaking, I prefer to use an intermediary varible anyways, as ternaries in classnames are hard to read. So `const col =  index === 1 || index === item.length - 2 ? 8 : 4` + `className={"whatever" + col}`  much easier and no issues w/ order of operations .

Comment: Could you update your answer I'm finding it hard to understnad what you mean, sorry to be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarity after the answer from @Yuji 'Tomita' Tomita

The source code that works looks like this:

```
                    {instagramItems.map((item, index) => (
                        <div Key={index} onClick={() => handleClick(item, index)} className={"image-block col-sm-" + (index === 1 || index === instagramItems.length - 2 ? 8 : 4) } style={{
                                    backgroundImage: "url(" + item.media_url + ")",
                                    backgroundPosition: 'center ',
                                    backgroundSize: 'cover',
                                    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
                                }}></div>
                    ))}
```